# JavaScript local scope variable available in event after host function returns. Why?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, garbage-collection

So... I come from c++ background and I don't understand few things about JS. For example:

```
function a()
{
   var x = 0; // Local variable

   $(document).on('mousedown', function(){console.log('down: ', x++);});
   $(document).on('mouseup', function(){console.log('up: ', x++);});
   setInterval(function(){console.log('interval: ', x++);}, 1000);

   //W3schools: 'Local variables are deleted when the function is completed.'
}
a();
```

Why the console output looks like this? (while random clicking)

```
interval:  0
down:  1
up:  2
interval:  3
down:  4
up:  5
interval:  6
down:  7
interval:  8
up:  9
interval:  10
down:  11
interval:  12
up:  13
interval:  14
down:  15
up:  16
interval:  17
interval:  18
```

I expected it to be 'undefined's or NaNs or nulls since x should be removed at the end of the scope, but it seems that all three callback reference it just fine forever... why? Is it a new behavior or it works like this since old JS versions? I can't find an answer.

Comment: That's how closures work in javascript. It's a plenty of answers about closures here on SO.

Comment: To add to @Andrey comment, there is a good explanation in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure) with a similar example. Basically, the instances of the three **inner anonymous functions** keep a reference to the variable `x` in they lexical environment, so the variable `x` can't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3schools' comment is incomplete. Most of the time, variables do get cleaned up when a function finishes (not necessarily instantly, but the next time garbage collection runs). But that's only because most of the time there are no more references to those variables.

However, since javascript supports functions as first class objects, it also supports closures. When you have a line like this:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(){console.log('down: ', x++);});
```

...you are creating a closure. That closure is the new function, plus the lexical environment in which it was defined. It has a reference to `x`, and so even once `a` finishes resolving, that `x` will not be garbage collected. Later when the function is called, it can still access the closure variables just fine.

`x` can still potentially be garbage collected, but only if all the closures referencing it get garbage collected as well. In this case, you'd achieve that by unregistering the mouseup and mousedown events, and cancelling the interval.

Answer (score 0):

The functions can access x because you gave them that variable in a scope where it was accessible. It counts up because in javascript you don't give the actual value but just a reference to it, so all your callbacks still reference the x inside the a() function. And because it's still referenced javascript's garbagecollector won't delete it because it thinks it's still 'in use', which it is (because your callback functions use it to increase it every call).